# About unbounded linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

I'm reading the chapterfrom a optimization book and cannot understand the example listed below:"

[image: Captured from P105]
"
Actually i have seen its linear. My question is why f is unbounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_n = \{0, 0, …, 1, 0, …\}$ where $1$ is in the $n^{th}$ slot, but $0$ elsewhere. Then $|f(e_n)| = n$ and $|e_n|=1$. Since $n$ is arbitrarily large, it must be that $f$ is unbounded.